# Structure with mean and multipcation

Tags: logic

Let S be a structure that contains {0,1} as the basic elements and has the multiplication operation and average operation $\frac{a+b}{2}$ 
Show that all of the elements in this structure are in the form $a=\frac{m}{2^n}$ Where$ n,m\in{N}$ and $0\le a\le1$. I'm having problem showing that each $a$ in this form can be built using this operation as I don't see the algorithm to create every such number.

Comment: You don't need to generate all of the numbers. You just have to show that any number in $S$ has the form $\frac{m}{2^n}$ and that $0\le a\le 1$.

Comment: You should begin from 0 and 1, and do the operation a couple of times to understand what it does (draw the corresponding dots you obtain on the segment (0,1)), and show the result for n =1, 2, 3...

Comment: I can easily show that every number has this form. My question is how do I show that every number in this form is in S.

Comment: Am I reading the problem incorrectly? "Show that all of the elements in this structure are in the form ". Doesn't that mean you are done?

Comment: I think it is, my mistake on writing the question. I still want to know how to prove the other way around.

Comment: For the other direction. a) Start with $\{0,1\}$. b) Use these to generate $1 \over 2$. Now you have $\{0,{1 \over 2},1\}$. c) Use these to generate $1 \over 4$ and $3\over 4$. Now you have $\{0,{1 \over 4},{1 \over 2},{3 \over 4},1\}$. d) Can you see where this is going?

Comment: What you want to show does not seem to be true -- for example, $S=\mathbb R$ satisfies your conditions but contains plenty of elements that are not on the form $m/2^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to show that $a \in S$ whenever $a=\frac{m}{2^n}$ and $m\le 2^{n}$ for $m,n \in N$. I would proceed by mathematical induction on $n$.

If $n=0$, then $a=0$ or $a=1$, both of which are in $S$, so the basis step is satisfied. Now, assume $a=\frac{m}{2^n} \in S$ for all $m\le 2^{n}$. Suppose $m \le 2^{n+1}$ and $a=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}$. Then, we may write $m=k \cdot 2^{n} + r$ for $k=0$ or $1$ and $r \le 2^{n}$. Consequently,
$$
a=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{k \cdot 2^{n} + r}{2^{n}})=\frac{1}{2}(k+\frac{r}{2^{n}})
$$
Now, $k=0$ or $1$, so $k \in S$. By the induction hypothesis, $\frac{r}{2^{n}} \in S$. Therefore, by the averaging rule, $a=\frac{1}{2}(k+\frac{r}{2^{n}}) \in S$. This completes the induction step and thus the proof.